# Decoding Opus buffer Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, opus, raw-data

I am trying to decode an Opus buffer which library should I use.

Comment: you might look at node-opus .. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-opus

Comment: I tried to use this library but it doesn't work or maybe I can't understand how to use

Comment: its an npm module, used as follow:  clone it from the git source code at : https://github.com/Rantanen/node-opus .. cd to the root dir for the project..   install it with  "npm install"  .. run tests with "npm run test"  ... then start drilling down into the details..

Comment: Use [`opus-stream-decoder`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opus-stream-decoder). See the NodeJS example in the [test-opus-stream-decoder.js](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/blob/master/dist/test-opus-stream-decoder.js) file: